# Riemann integrable proof of a formula with partitions

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ verifies $F' = f$, then

$$
F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(t)dt
$$

Hint: if $P=(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, write

$$
F(b)-F(a) = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1})
$$

Comment: Can we assume the fundamental theorem of calculus here? Or is that what you are (essentially) trying to prove?

Comment: I think is with the definition of integral, in fact the topic that i'm seeing is Riemann-Stieltjes integral, so I don't think that the fundamental theorem would be assumable

Comment: Okay then. I don't know what approach are you exactly expected to take, but there's an idea: first off, you will have to prove the FTC, which is not particularly hard but somewhat tricky if you don't remember the details. Now, prove that if two functions have the same derivative in an interval, they differ at a constant. Finally, if $G(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$, $G + c =  F$, Hence, $F(b) - F(a)$ = $G(b) - G(a)$ = $\int_a^bf(t)dt - \int_a^af(t)dt = \int_a^bf(t)dt - 0 = \int_a^bf(t)dt$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the mean value theorem there are points $\xi_j \in (x_{j-1},x_j)$ such that

$$F(b) - F(a) = \sum_{j=1}^n [F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})] = \sum_{j=1}^n F'(\xi_j)(x_j - x_{j-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi_j)(x_j - x_{j-1}). $$

Do you recognize the sum on the RHS?